# Is there a way to force a web app link to be opened always in Safari for IOS mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am currently using the MediaRecorder API in my web app which works fine on Safari for IOS mobile devices, but if the same URL is opened in any other browsers, none of the audio recorder APIs work.

What I want is to detect if the user isn't on Safari and redirect them to Safari, or either create a link that opens specifically in Safari only, like `googlechrome://www.example.com` which opens the link Chrome. Any suggestions or workarounds are appreciated.

I can't find any documentation to open a link by default in Safari browser only on IOS mobile devices

This is the MediaRecorder API I am using:

```
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
```

Comment: No. The program used to open a URL is determined by the client device. You cannot override that. Your time would be better spent making your code work cross-browser instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, is there a cross-browser audio recorder api that works with third party browsers on IOS mobile devices like chrome / firefox